# Flex-wrap режет кол-во элементов

Tags: html, css

На сайте есть блок с брендами, прописан флексами.[image]

При ширине 992px прописываю @media:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается вот такой слайдер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как, думаю, видно, он содержимое обрезается по левому краю, а также, если пролистать до конца, элементов не хватает.  Пробовал гуглить, в свойствах flex-wrap написано, что значение nowrap может привести к переполнению контейнера, если это тот случай, то как это фиксится через CSS? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ввиду отсутствия внятного примера, смею предложить взять за основу такой вариант:

```css
.brands-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
}

.brands-list>div {
  margin: 7px;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px blue;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .brands-list {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .brands-list>div { margin: 0 15px 0 0; }
  .brands-list>div:first-child { margin: 0 15px 0 15px; }
  .brands-list>div:last-child { position: relative; }
  .brands-list>div:last-child::after {
    content: '\a0';
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="brands-list"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div><div>12</div><div>13</div><div>14</div><div>15</div><div>16</div><div>17</div><div>18</div><div>19</div><div>20</div></div>
```